# Повторный вход в контейнер в docker

Tags: linux, docker

Допустим я запустил контейнер таким образом:

`docker run -ti my_super_images bash`

Спустя какое-то время я ввожу exit и выхожу из него. Теперь информация о нем содержится только в `docker ps -a`. Как мне снова войти в терминал контейнера, зная его id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указанный в соседнем ответе пример сработает, чтобы зайти в работающий контейнер и запустить дополнительный процесс, но ничего не сделает с остановленным, как описано в задаче.

```
docker run -ti --name test-subject ubuntu
root@6d7a294a9450:/# exit

---

docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
6d7a294a9450        ubuntu              "/bin/bash"              2 minutes ago       Exited (0) About a minute ago                       test-subject

---

docker exec -ti test-subject bash
Error response from daemon: Container 6d7a294a9450b81420c8cf25357a580c3f05f25fae5bc03e890d9b5737c1b266 is not running
```

Для того, чтобы зайти в остановленный, его сначала надо запустить

```
docker start test-subject
```

В конкретно этом случае контейнер сразу выйдет, потому что его основной процесс - bash, который не сможет читать STDIN и не получил команды, и в этом случае интересует прицепиться к основному прцоессу, нежели запустить в контейнере еще один процесс. Поэтому надо прямо указать docker, что надо подцепить STDIN к тому процессу, который будет запущен через start:

```
docker start -ia test-subject
root@6d7a294a9450:/#
```

voila

Answer (score 4):

```
docker exec -ti имя_контейнера bash
```

можно зайти под определенным юзером с директивой -user user_name

Comment: Error response from daemon: Container 6d7a294a9450b81420c8cf25357a580c3f05f25fae5bc03e890d9b5737c1b266 is not running ¯\_(ツ)_/¯